# Filter Out Values by Category into new Table with vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

I have the following data that contains a list of Agents and their respective Manager:

[image]
I need to filter out the agents by manager and put them into a new table for each Manager?

I tried with the vlookup as seen in the picture but seems like as soon as the function finds a value, it will stick to that one.

The blue tables is the result that I want to get. I guess it has to be a function for each new table - that's fine!

I could try using VBA, with a for loop but I figured that I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLOOKUP()` will always find the first occurrence of the lookup_value.

`INDEX(array, row_num,[column_num])` could list the Agents if you gave it the `row_num` of each one as it was filled down.

Let's start by getting an *array* (list) of the row numbers of the Agents for Mark.  This expression

`IF($E$2:$E$9=I$1,ROW($E$1:$E$8))`

checks to see where column E equals `I$1` (Mark), and wherever it is, it returns a number from the list of row numbers for rows 1 to 8.  In the positions where column E does not equal Mark, the expression returns `False`.  So the actual array that this expression gives is `{1,FALSE,3,FALSE,5,FALSE,7,FALSE}`.  Note that the number that's returned for each of Mark's Agents is actually one less than their row number.

Next we want to list those numbers as the formula is filled down, while ignoring the `FALSE` values.  `SMALL(array, k)` returns the kth smallest value from `array`. As it's filled down, `ROW(I1)` increments and the numbers are listed in order:

`SMALL(IF($E$2:$E$9=I$1,ROW($E$1:$E$8)),ROW(I1))`

Now we can use that expression for the `row_num`'s in an `INDEX()` function to get the names of Mark's Agents:

`=INDEX($F$2:$F$9,SMALL(IF($E$2:$E$9=I$1,ROW($E$1:$E$8)),ROW(I1)))`

This expression returns the value in `F2:F9` corresponding to the number supplied by `SMALL()`.  So, as it's filled down, it lists the names of Mark's Agents.  You can use this formula to list the Agents, but see the note below.

If it's filled down farther than the number of Agents that Mark has, it will give a `#N/A!` error.  Those can be converted into blanks by wrapping the whole formula in an `IFERROR()`:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$9,SMALL(IF($E$2:$E$9=I$1,ROW($E$1:$E$8)),ROW(I1))),"")`

This formula, filled down and right from I2, gives the results shown below.

[image]

Note that this is an array formula, so it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is a rather long-winded explanation for the formula, but I hope it helps.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. A lot of work just to get the job done. Excel should have a built in function for this. However, I just tried your function and works perfectly fine. I appreciate that.